# How to oracle call own type member function

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

I created a SQL object:

```
create type foo_type as object (
        bar integer(2),
        bar2  varchar(200),

        member function get return integer
)
```

and I implemented my type's body:

```
CREATE TYPE BODY foo_type as
member function get return integer is
begin
   return bar;
END;
END;
```

Then I created a table with this type:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    foo1 foo_type
)
```

and I inserted a row:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (foo1) VALUES (foo_type(1, 'a'))
```

I would like that this is callable like this:

```
SELECT foo1.get() FROM test_table
```

but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to use an alias when referencing type methods/attributes.

eg alias the table to t:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO test_table (foo1) VALUES (foo_type(1, 'a'));

1 row created.

SQL> select t.foo1.get() from test_table t;

T.FOO1.GET()
------------
           1
```